# How to force Facebook to update an og:image that the scraper didn't download correctly?

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, social-media, open-graph-protocol

My case is like this: I load the `og:image` by my own CDN (like this: https://cdn03.indozone.id/content/2019/05/14/WYsbvr/t_5cda33b9072e5_700.jpg).

Sometimes, when I share to social media (Facebook for example), the image wouldn't load. Or it will take a long time to load like this (1st case):

[image]

Image is around `160kb`, resolution is on `700x525` pixel. And when it take too long to load, it will become like this (2nd case):

[image]

My question is: **is there any open graph meta tag that will prevent facebook to load the broken image** on the 2nd case? Or is there any CDN optimization needed for facebook to load the image faster?

This is the sample of my current meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cdn03.indozone.id/content/2019/05/10/r8sZ11/t_5cd523313da93_700.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="700" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="525" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Lenovo Rilis Tiga Laptop ThinkPad Yang Dibekali Dengan AMD Ryzen 7 Pro" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lenovo belum lama ini telah meluncurkan laptop seri ThinkPad..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://dev.indozone.id/tech/r8sZ11/lenovo-rilis-tiga-laptop-thinkpad-yang-dibekali-dengan-amd-ryzen-7-pro" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can force Facebook to re-fetch the meta data of a given URL [by entering it in this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and selecting the option `Fetch new scrape information`. This is useful when you change (or add) open graph tags and you want the results to be immediately detected.

The tool will display the metadata it found on the input URL and will update accordingly its representation.